# Exibir um type numered-list de um graphql

Tags: javascript, jsx, graphql, richtextbox, next.js

Olá! Estou com enorme dificuldade de chegar nos dados de uma uma numbered-list de um richtext pelo 'graphcms'(um CMS) para exibir em um blog com nextjs, formatado.
Eu consigo chegar até o type por um switch(type), mas não estou conseguindo correr um .map para listar na tela.
Bom, segue o código com algumas info e teste, não sei se consegui ser claro:

- Um adendo, o `class='list-decimal'` é do tailwind
- Outro adendo, espero receber:

1. lista numerada um
2. lista numerada dois
3. lista numerada três

   1. lista numerada um dentro do três
   2. lista numerada dois dentro do três
4. lista numerada quatro
5. lista numerada cinco

Estou recebendo `aqui: undefined` cinco vezes

Alguém sabe ajudar o noob aqui?

```js
const getContentFragment = (index, text, obj, type) => {

  switch (type) {
    case 'numbered-list':
      return <p key={index} class="list-decimal"> 
                <ol>
                  {modifiedText.map((item, i) => 
                    <li key={i}>                  
                      {item}
                      {console.log('aqui:',item)}                      
                    </li>)
                  }
                </ol>
              </p>;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Consegui chegar no `text`, mas não estou conseguindo deixar o indice do array dinâmico para ir buscando os outros valores do array:

```js
          case 'numbered-list':
            return <p key={index} class="list-decimal">
                      <ol>
                        {modifiedText.map((n,i) => 
                          <React.Fragment key={i}>
                            <li>

                              {console.log('aqui', obj.children[0].children[0].children[0].text)}    
                              {obj.children[0].children[0].children[0].text}


                            </li>                  
                          </React.Fragment>
                          )
                        }
                      </ol>
                    </p>;
```

Estou recendo a linha 0 estática 5 vezes, não consegui deixar o `children[0]` com o indice ao inves de 0.
Alguém sabe como faço?